# How to export Redshift table data to local file via JDBC?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there anyway could export redshift table data into a local file as dump via JDBC?

Thanks

Comment: Do you only consider JDBC or is your question more general - just how to export the data to a file? For the latter, you can use psql: `psql -h $host -U $user -d $database -t -A -c "select * from $source"`

Answer (score 1):

The most performant way to extract data is not through JDBC but using the UNLOAD command to dump data into Amazon S3. After the data is extracted, you can then download it directly from S3, as needed. By using JDBC you will be limited by I/O and network performance. UNLOAD benefits from parallelization and very low-level, high-throughput connections between Redshift (EC2, actually) and S3.

Examples:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html

Answer (score 0):

The application you are using to connect to Redshift via JDBC would be responsible for saving the data to a "local file".

For example, it could send a `SELECT * FROM <table>` command to Redshift. The data is then returned to the application, which could then save it to disk.

Take a look at apps such as SQL Workbench/J, DBVisualizer and Aginity. They should all offer that capability.

Comment: But in this way, the performance is very slow, right? I was thinking of if there is any built-in tool in Redshift, likes pg_dump in Postgre, could do this job quickly.

Comment: The only built-in tool for exporting data from Amazon Redshift is the `UNLOAD` command, which saves data into Amazon S3 as CSV files (which can be automatically gzipped).